# How to split files in SpringBatch to process item independently?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I have a SpringBatch that process XML files with a XStreamMarshaller and store it into a Document Java Object. All is fine and my XML File look like :

```
<?xml ...... ?>
<Document>
    ...
    ...
</Document>
```

But, sometimes, the batch receive invalid XML files, with multiple root tag like this :

```
<?xml ...... ?>
<Document>
    ...
    ...
</Document>
<?xml ...... ?>
<Document>
    ...
    ...
</Document>
```

This is "**Normal**" and **i can do nothing to change this behavior**.
And so, when this kinf of XML is processed, the reader cannot parse it.

Is there a way to split this file into multiple file with only one Document, using springBatch.
I know how to do this in JAVA, but i would like to avoid creating another java process to do this.
So, if someone know how to do this with springBatch...

Thank you